# Prefer if evaluations

Tags: objective-c

Which would be the preferred method?   With the assuming that myInteger 99.99% of time will have a valid value and this method will get called very rapidly.

```
-(BOOL)validDate
{
    NSUInteger myInteger = ...//method to obtain value;    
    if (myInteger != NSNotFound)
        return YES;        
    return NO;
}


-(BOOL)validDate
{
    NSUInteger myInteger = ...//method to obtain value;    
    if (myInteger == NSNotFound)
        return NO;        
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: If you were voting to close this question, please explain?

Comment: People are voting to close because they think any answer would be opinion based.  This is nonsense because the correct answer is that it doesn't really matter.  The difference is one machine instruction.  Also, Wain's answer is my preferred one.

Comment: Questions of this nature would probably be better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Also, I'd really recommend you pick up a copy of the book CODE COMPLETE 2 which answers questions like this. In general, the book recommends to put the most often hit case first.

Comment: I am surprised that the question was misunderstood of its intent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The preferred would be:

```
- (BOOL)validDate
{
    NSUInteger myInteger = ...//method to obtain value;    

    return (myInteger != NSNotFound);
}
```

because it doesn't actually need to execute a branch.

Note that the difference will be imperceptibly small unless you are running this code a lot...

Comment: "Note that the difference will be imperceptibly small unless you are running this code a lot..." If you're strictly talking about code execution, absolutely. However, if you take code readability also into consideration, this is definitely the preferred approach.

Comment: @user523234, even called rapidly the difference will be pretty small due to the way that branch statements are handled in modern processors. Don't worry about performance till you have reason to. Worry about accuracy and readability.

Comment: Your answer is my preferred approach but not because of performance.  I think it is the most readable solution.

Comment: "Note that the difference will be imperceptibly small unless you are running this code a lot..."  I disagree. The comparison will occur regardless of the value of myInteger, and since there are equal number of instructions on both sides of the if-branches, both forms have an equal performance hit.

Answer (score 1):

Neither form is preferred as far as standards are concerned. The comparison will occur regardless of the value of `myInteger`, so both forms are equal in regards to performance. The only thing I would change would be the naming of the method itself. It would be advantageous to adhere to Apple's Coding Guidelines for Cocoa when naming methods and variables. Per Apple's guidelines:

> If the property is expressed as an adjective, the format is:

```
- (BOOL)isAdjective;

- (void)setAdjective:(BOOL)flag;
```

In this case, since `validDate` is an adjective (it describes the state of the object), you should prefix the method name with `is`, as in `- (BOOL)isValidDate`.  See [Apple's Coding Guidelines for more information](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingMethods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001282-1004202-BCIGGFCC).

Comment: +1 for this "The comparison will occur regardless of the value of myInteger, so both forms are equal in regards to performance. "  The rest were not what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If the choice is strictly between the two options you gave I'd go with

```
-(BOOL)validDate
{
    NSUInteger myInteger = ...//method to obtain value;    
    if (myInteger == NSNotFound)
        return NO;        
    return YES;
}
```

for readability.  I don't like reading double negations like `!= NSNotFound`.